# Problema de carga de estilos o imágenes o las dos cosas, en sitios creados en wordpress como dominio directorio en un vps

Tags: wordpress, dominio, vps

Hola a la Comunidad!...
Mi problema particular es el siguiente:
Cuando creo sitios en formato directorio de wordpress (en un host vps) - ej: dominio.com/directorio - los Problemas que me surgen son: o no se visualizan estilos e imágenes o no se visualizan imágenes y si estilos. 
El problema particular es en la creación de directorios en los dominios, creando directamente en el dominio o en forma de multisitio, todo funciona correctamente, pero no así en directorios.
Como estoy en modo de prueba en un vps de hostinger, estoy queriendo solucionar esto que me pasa propiamente con la creación de directorios, los parámetros de apuntar el dominio a dicho ip del vps y la configuración del ssl al menos desde el soporte de hostinger se ve todo correcto, por eso necesitaría una orientación de que más tengo que revisar y probar para poder solucionar este problema. Si se necesitan mas detalles o información me preguntan por favor.
Gracias por cualquier ayuda :)

 Capturas de los problemas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sin carga de estilos e imagenes (imagen de arriba) o sin carga de imagenes y si estilos(en la imagen de abajo) suele variar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]